# Усатый нянь or what to call a male nanny (babysitter)?

Tags: лексикон, род

Following [the question about common feminine suffices for profession titles](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/487/suffixes-for-feminine-professions-%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0-%D1%8B%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0).

Word `няня` has several meanings. According to [gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%ED%FF%ED%FF&all=x):

> **1.** Работница, занимающаяся уходом, присмотром за детьми (в семье, в детском саду, в яслях). 
>   **2.** Разг. Санитарка в лечебном учреждении.

What would you call a male `няня` in both cases? In documents or in common speech?

Also I would appreciate comments about similar cases: `горничная`,`медицинская сестра`. Is  `медбрат` common and official word in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though it's perfectly valid to call women grammatically masculine names, the opposite is quite peculiar (see [this answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/324/134) of mine).

To sound neutral, the names of professions which lack gramatically masculine forms, are replaced by the synonyms, even if they are bulky:

- *Помощник воспитателя* instead of *нянечка* (in a kindergarten)
- *Санитар* instead of *нянечка* (in a hospital)
- *Медицинский брат* instead of *медицинская сестра*
- *Артист балета* instead of *балерина*

Sidorenko in *Теоретические и практические материалы по морфологии современного русского языка* writes:

> Для называния лиц мужского пола, выполняющих соответствующую работу, иногда используются описательные обороты типа *артист (солист) балета, переписчик на машинке*. Могут быть использованы также новые слова с изменением основы: *дояр* от *доярка*, *уборщик* от *уборщица*)

For a male babysitter in a kindergarten you can use *воспитатель*, *младший воспитатель* or *помощник воспитателя*.

For a visiting male babysitter, you can use a loanword *бебиситтер* (which unequivocally means a visiting babysitter)

Comment: however санитар/медбрат learns сестринское дело :)

Comment: The masculine form of балерина is балерон I think.

Answer (score 3):

```
What would you call a male няня in both cases? In documents or in common speech?
```

Воспитатель, гувернёр.

```
горничная,
```

Never seen a male in that office. Possibly "уборщик" (cleaner), "слуга" (servant). In military, "денщик".

```
медицинская сестра. Is медбрат common and official word in this case?
```

Yes. Also "санитар" is used.

Comment: I like your answer, but isn't гувернёр a little outdated?

Comment: It was used in pre-revolutionary Russia and now the word revives. This only applies to privately-hired personnel, e.g. in kindergarten it would be воспитатель, in private house it would be either воспитатель or гувернёр (depending on the wishes of the host to look old-fashinable).

Comment: In pre-revolutionary Russia male chambermaids were quite common and were called *номерной*. I've heard this word once from a Russian-speaking hostess in a Tunisian hotel.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от конкретных обязанностей.

1.
В семье:
- "Нянь" - шутливо.
- "Няня-мужчина" - официально. Если этот мужчина занимается еще и воспитанием детей (а не только уходом за ними), то "гувернёр", "воспитатель", "няня-воспитатель". Если кроме ухода за детьми занимается работой по дому - "горничный", "домработник" (наиболее официально), "эконом".
- "Слуга" - уничижительно.

В детском саду: "воспитатель", "работник детского сада".

2.
"Санитар", "медбрат"